# View NVVM IR file

Tags: cuda

I have CUDA 5.5 setup on my machine. I want to do some compiler transformations so I would like to work on NVVM IR file. I heard that with CUDA 5.5, we can get IR file and write passes around libNVVM. I am not able to proper documentation for that. Can anyone please provide basic steps to get NVVM IR file from input .cu file?

Answer (score 5):

Two presentations that give some background on this:

- From GTC 2012, [￼￼Compiling CUDA and Other Languages for GPUs](http://www.gputechconf.com/gtcnew/on-demand-gtc.php?searchByKeyword=compiling+cuda&searchItems=&sessionTopic=&sessionEvent=&sessionYear=2012&sessionFormat=&submit=&select=+#1348) explains the architecture and roadmap.
- From GTC 2013, [Building Accelerated DSLs and GPU Compilers with libNVVM](http://www.gputechconf.com/gtcnew/on-demand-gtc.php?searchByKeyword=yuan&searchItems=&sessionTopic=&sessionEvent=&sessionYear=2013&sessionFormat=&submit=&select=%20#2355).

At the moment you cannot extract the NVVM IR from a .cu file, for that you would need the CUDA C front end (named libcuda.lang in the [GTC2012 presentation](http://www.gputechconf.com/gtcnew/on-demand-gtc.php?searchByKeyword=compiling+cuda&searchItems=&sessionTopic=&sessionEvent=&sessionYear=2012&sessionFormat=&submit=&select=+#1348)). With CUDA 5.5 libnvvm is distributed with the toolkit, libnvvm takes NVVM IR and outputs the PTX. CUDA 5.5 also includes libdevice for device side operations from NVVM IR.